# low pass filtering for smoothing

Tags: lowpass-filter, smoothing, averaging

I am using the following code in Matlab, from some source (sadly I cant remember).
The code is used for smoothing signals using a low pas filter.

```
 function y = fftSmooth(resp,srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow)
    L      = length(resp);
    window = zeros(1,L);
    window(floor((L-srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow+1)/2)...
    :floor((L+srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow)/2))=1;

    % zero phase low pass filtering
    tmp = ifft(fft(resp).*fft(window)/srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow);      
    y=-1*ifft(fft(-1*tmp).*fft(window)/srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow);
```

I have removed some unnecessary parts to shorten the code.

My question: how exactly is the filter designed (the last two lines)? Shouldn't it be in the time domain?

Comment: I think what you mean is "how is the filtering **implemented**" (which is different from how the filter is *designed*). The answer to that is it's implemented in the frequency domain, which is perfectly fine. I wouldn't have implemented it as such though, but that's a different topic.

Comment: See also: [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70605/63763)

Comment: @Jdip, thanks, its was very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code apparently originate from **BreathMetrics (Matlab toolbox for analyzing respiratory recordings)**: [breathmetrics/fftsmooth.m](https://github.com/zelanolab/breathmetrics/blob/master/breathmetrics_functions/fftSmooth.m). It is descripted in [Automated analysis of breathing waveforms using BreathMetrics: A respiratory signal processing toolbox](https://doi.org/10.1093/chemse/bjy045), Chemical Senses, 2018. [A draft is here](https://github.com/zelanolab/breathmetrics/blob/master/NotoBreathmetricsChemicalSenses2018.pdf).

Below, the function is visualyy decomposed into frequency/time steps. As @Jdip wrote, that is a filter implementation in the frequency domain.

```
%%% function y = fftSmooth(resp,srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow)

%Set inputs
lResp = 2048;
resp = randn(1,lResp)+10*exp(-(((1:lResp)-lResp/2)/(0.01*lResp)).^2);
srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow = 16;

    L      = length(resp);
    window = zeros(1,L);
    window(floor((L-srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow+1)/2)...
    :floor((L+srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow)/2))=1;

    % zero phase low pass filtering
    tmp = ifft(fft(resp).*fft(window)/srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow);      
    y=-1*ifft(fft(-1*tmp).*fft(window)/srateCorrectedSmoothedWindow);
  
    figure(1);clf
    subplot(2,1,2)
plot([resp;y]')  
axis tight;legend('Time Signal','Time Signal filtered')
    subplot(2,1,1)
yyaxis left
plot(abs(fft(resp)))
yyaxis right
plot(abs(fft(window)))
axis tight;legend('Spectrum','Window')
```

[image: Decomposition of algorithm]